# cooled or cool usage

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives

I saw a sentence labeled on a packaging, saying Do not reheat once **cooled**. I am wondering why here they used cooled rather than cool. and in turn, another question that can we say eat (serve) **cool** (cold) or serve cooled follows.

Answer (score 1):

Complete version:

> Do not reheat [this] once [it is] cooled.

For your next sentence, "eat *cool* food" and "eat *cooled* food" both seem valid. Here *cool* and *cooled* are both used as adjectives, which are opposite to "hot". "Cooled food" could be transformed to "food that is cooled".